# Can't get an url with requests

Tags: python, python-requests

### For my work I am trying to automate a websearch and dataquery, we are monitoring prices online of commercial part numbers every week which takes me at least 2h. It is repetitive and boring, I would like to automate it.

This is basically my first try with beautifulsoup, I read and watch some videos about it. If someone has the perfect tuto, pease share, I am a bit lost ;)

So I tried to get the HTML code from the url : 
'https://www.bom.ai/ic/STM32F030C8T6.html', but i get an error message and that whatever url i give. 
// For the moment i strictly followed examples I found on the net
// I tried on simpler website, a wikipedia page, my very very basic html page... always the same error message

```
import requests
import urllib.request
import time
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

def create_website(CP):
    return(str('https://www.bom.ai/ic/'+str(CP)+'.html'))

url=create_website('STM32F030C8T6')

response=requests.get(url)
```

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='en.wikipedia.org',
>   port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /wiki/Cam%C3%A9lia_Jordana
>   (Caused by
>   NewConnectionError(': Failed to establish a new connection:
>   [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected
>   party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established
>   connection failed because connected host has failed to respond'))

Comment: Beautifulsoup is an HTML parser. You are having troubles with `requests`.

Comment: No problem here. Maybe the site was down for a moment or you have local network problems.

Comment: And your error should match your actual code.

Comment: Your code works for me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mentionned you were working, you might have a company proxy blocking your request! You can try the following :

- with proxy (if you configured it on your machine (it might be done by your company)):

```
import requests
r = requests.get('your_url')
print(r.text)
```

- without proxy:

```
import requests
proxy = {
    'http_proxy': '',
    'https_proxy': ''}
r = requests.get('your_url', proxies=proxy)
print(r.text)
```

Try both!